# How to filter and modify array according to one value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array:

```
[
  {name: "test", value: "test", group: 0},
  {name: "test1", value: "test2", group: 0},
  {name: "test3", value: "test3", group: 1},
  {name: "test4", value: "test4", group: 1},
  {name: "test5", value: "test5", group: 1},
  {name: "test6", value: "tes6t", group: 2},
  {name: "test7", value: "test7", group: 2},
]
```

I need that this array would look like this :

```
[
  {name: "test", value: "test", group: 0, selections: [
    {name: "test", value: "test", group: 0},
    {name: "test1", value: "test1", group: 0}
  ]},
  {name: "test3", value: "test3", group: 1, selections: [
    {name: "test3", value: "test3", group: 1},
    {name: "test4", value: "test4", group: 1},
    {name: "test5", value: "test5", group: 1}
  ]},
  {name: "test6", value: "tes6t", group: 2, selections: [
    {name: "test6", value: "tes6t", group: 2},
    {name: "test7", value: "test7", group: 2}
  ]},
]
```

Filtering for the same items according to group value then adding all of the same items to the first element selections array, including the first one.

How to achieve it in the best way without multiple for arrays in  JavaScript/TypeScript?

Comment: Can't you just use a for loop? I don't think you can filter and create a new array with just a single array.

Comment: I am asking for a proper answer without multiple for loops (I can have this done with multiple for loops, but its not really the good idea - its time consuming)

Comment: Sorry but what is wrong with using multiple for-loops here?

Comment: You are suggesting me to get the first value , check if there are others, push it to selections, then get the second value , run it through loop again, and do it for every value in my array , could be hundreds loops.

Comment: You should be able to do this in two nested foreach loops

Comment: @Devla While `map`/`reduce`/`filter` all hide the loops behind the scenes and can be moderately better optimised, they do still have to loop through each item, so the performance differences are generally minimal. (Not saying you should do it one way or the other, just worth pointing out)

Comment: @yudhiesh because it says so on the homework sheet. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
const input = [
  {name: "test", value: "test", group: 0},
  {name: "test1", value: "test2", group: 0},
  {name: "test3", value: "test3", group: 1},
  {name: "test4", value: "test4", group: 1},
  {name: "test5", value: "test5", group: 1},
  {name: "test6", value: "tes6t", group: 2},
  {name: "test7", value: "test7", group: 2},
];

const groupBy = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.group] ? acc[cur.group].selections.push(cur) : acc[cur.group] = {
    ...cur,
    selections: [ cur ]
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(groupBy);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

As so often [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#How_reduce_works) proves itself to be very handy at such tasks ...

```js
function collectItemByGroupAndSelection(collector, groupItem) {
  const { index, list } = collector;
  const { group: groupKey } = groupItem;

  let selectionGroup = index[groupKey];
  if (!selectionGroup) {

    selectionGroup = index[groupKey] = {
      ...groupItem,
      selections: [],
    };
    list.push(selectionGroup);
  }
  selectionGroup.selections.push({ ...groupItem });
  
  return collector;
}

const sampleData = [
  {name: "test", value: "test", group: 0},
  {name: "test1", value: "test2", group: 0},
  {name: "test3", value: "test3", group: 1},
  {name: "test4", value: "test4", group: 1},
  {name: "test5", value: "test5", group: 1},
  {name: "test6", value: "tes6t", group: 2},
  {name: "test7", value: "test7", group: 2},
];

console.log(
  "array result directly via the collector's `list` property ...",
  sampleData.reduce(collectItemByGroupAndSelection, {

    index: {},
    list: [],

  }).list
);

console.log(
  "the collector's `index` object ...",
  sampleData.reduce(collectItemByGroupAndSelection, {

    index: {},
    list: [],

  }).index
);

// the next example of cause is not needed since the approach
// within one iteration cycle already does builds both data
// structures an object and an array based one ...

console.log(
  "processing the `index` object by `Object.values` ...",
  Object.values(
    sampleData.reduce(collectItemByGroupAndSelection, {

      index: {},
      list: [],

    }).index
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```